# Getting Permission denied after pushing into github

Tags: github

While pushing I am getting the below error, how can I fix this?

`$ git push origin ramya_v1`

> remote: Permission to xxx/xxx. git denied to TechieGenie.
>   fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/xxx/xxx.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403**

Answer (score 0):

First of all does the repo your trying to publish to exist?

Go to https://github.com/YourGithubUsername/TargetRepo if it says ‘Not found’ then you need to **create one**. To create one you can go to: https://github.com/new and create a new repository there. Then try again.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your git client is unable to authenticate. 
Enable storing of credentials using

```
$ git config credential.helper store
```

Then try to push your repository, it will ask for your username and password.

```
$ git push origin ramya_v1
```

Enter your username and password and it will cache it for further requests.

Comment: @Ramya what is the exact error you are getting now? were you able to run the first statement?